# SwiftUI hide a view by touching outside of its bounds

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to implement pop up alert, which basicly are view that appears on another view, how can i dismiss this alert view on top, when i tap outside of white box?  [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCJsg.png)

My logic of calling this alert: I have my main view, where i have facebook signIn button, which should call this alert view, my alert view is just another swiftui view, which has UIViewRepresentable object inside to make hyperlinks inside my text.
MAIN VIEW:

```
 //
//  WelcomeView.swift
//  
//
//  
//

import SwiftUI
import FacebookLogin
import SDWebImageSwiftUI
import NavigationStack
import AVKit

struct WelcomeView: View {
    @State var showTermsAndConditionsAlert: Bool = false
            ZStack { // 1 outer
                ZStack { // 2 inner
                    VStack() {
                        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                            // my video player here
                            HStack {
                                // some other ui elements
                            }
                            VStack {
                               // logo
                                }
                            }
                        }                         
                        HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                            VStack {
                                Button(action: {
                                    appLog.debug("Continue with Facebook")
                                    showTermsAndConditionsAlert = true
                                }) {
                                    AuthButtonView(imageIdentifier: "ic_facebook", buttonTitle: "welcome_page_sign_up_btn_fb".localized)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .background(Color.blue)
                                        .cornerRadius(5)
                                }
                                // email button sign up
                                }
                                
                                // email button sign in
                                }) {

                                }
                                
                      // push views
                        }
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                    }
                    
                }
                .padding(.bottom, Theme.pageBottomPadding)
                
                if showTermsAndConditionsAlert {
                    TermsConditionsAlertView() {
                        self.showTermsAndConditionsAlert = false
                        self.viewModel.facebookLogin()
                    }
                }
            }
            .onTapGesture(perform: {
                // TODO: close dialog only when it is opened and press outside of dialog bound
                self.showTermsAndConditionsAlert = false
            })
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .automatic)
        .onAppear {
            self.player.isMuted = true
            self.player.play()
        }
        .onDisappear {
            self.player.pause()
        }
        .onReceive(viewModel.$state.dropFirst(), perform: { state in
           // switch state 
            }
        })
    }
}
```

ALERT VIEW: HyperLinkTextView - uirepresantable uiview

```
  //
//  TermsConditionsAlertView.swift
//  
//
//  
//

import SwiftUI
import NavigationStack

struct TermsConditionsAlertView: View {
    
    var callback: (() -> ())?
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.opacity(0.8).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                // Text here
                
                HyperLinkTextView(text: "terms_conditions_alert_view_description".localized,
                                  links: [Hyperlink(word: "terms_conditions".localized, url: NSURL(string: Constants.termsURL)!),
                                          Hyperlink(word: "privacy_policy".localized, url: NSURL(string: Constants.privacyPolicyURL)!)])
                  
                
                Button(action: {
                    appLog.debug("Agree and sign up pressed")
                    callback?()
                }) {
                   // button struct
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HYPERLINK UI VIEW:

```
//
//  HyperLinkTextView.swift
//  
//
//  
//

import SwiftUI

struct Hyperlink {
    var word: String
    var url: NSURL
}

struct HyperLinkTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    private var text: String
    private var links: [Hyperlink]
    
    init(text: String, links: [Hyperlink]) {
        self.text = text
        self.links = links
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> UITextView {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        links.forEach { hyperlink in
            let linkAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.link: hyperlink.url]
            
            var nsRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0)
            if let range = text.range(of: hyperlink.word) {
                nsRange = NSRange(range, in: text)
            }
            
            attributedString.setAttributes(linkAttributes, range: nsRange)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: NSNumber(value: 1), range: nsRange)
        }

        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.isEditable = false
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        textView.attributedText = attributedString
        textView.linkTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue]
        textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.font = UIFont(name: "ArialMT", size: 18)
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }
    
    public class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate, NSLayoutManagerDelegate {
        
        weak var textView: UITextView?
            
        public func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you done / tried so far?

Comment: I have a lot of code, all you can see on the image. I don't rly know how to provide a small part of it, so u can understand my issue

Comment: I can see you aren't using the built-in `Alert`, but maybe show at least how this works. Have you got your main view, and the alert in a `ZStack` where the alert is presented based on a `@State` value? Produce a minimal example in a new project and it will be easier to help

Comment: i added code, so you can clearly understand situation)

Answer (score 0):

Make a full screen view with a ZStack containing a view that is translucent, and put your alert on top of that. Add a tap gesture to the translucent view that dismisses the entire view.

Comment: when i tap inside of my alertView, it also closes

Comment: @ItaiAviv a few things to check: 1. The gesture is on the translucent view and not the ZStack, 2. The alertView is "above" the translucent view in the zstack, and 3. You may need to put an additional tap gesture on the alertView that does nothing.

Comment: 1) Yes 2) Yes 3) When i add empty tap gesture inside my alert view, it stop responds to any taps, didn't work